# JPA/HQL - Find rows with a to-many relationship that contains one or more specific elements

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I've got a `GrantedRole` class that allows a particular role to be granted across one or more `Site`'s, like:

```
public class GrantedRole {
    private RoleType role;

    private User granter;
    private User grantee;
    private Collection<Site> grantSites;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public UserRoleType getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public User getGranter() {
        return granter;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public User getGrantee() {
        return grantee;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    public Collection<Site> getGrantSites() {
        return grantSites;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to come up with is a query that will find all the `GrantedRole`'s that a particular granter has given out that have one or more specified `Site`'s in their `grantSites` collection.  So something like:

```
SELECT g FROM GrantedRole g WHERE g.granter = :granter AND 
    g.grantSites [contains at least one of] (:sites)
```

...but I'm not sure what syntax to use for `[contains at least one of]`, or if this is even possible using JPA/HQL.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make this work by adapting the answer found here:

[Checking the Intersection of Two Collections via HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083152/checking-the-intersection-of-two-collections-via-hql)

Specifically:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g FROM GrantedRole g, Site s WHERE g.granter = :granter 
    AND s IN (:sites) AND s IN ELEMENTS(g.grantSites) 
    ORDER BY g.grantee.firstName ASC, g.grantee.lastName ASC
```